# change value of existing variable without access main (index.php)

Tags: php, twig

I have problem to change value of `{{root.url}}` . I can't access index.php but just template file that made by twig.

i have to change it because i use https and by default this service just provide http. so i have to replace `{{root.url}}` and remove 'http' from value of `{{root.url}}`.

i can get new value with : `{{root.url|replace({ ('http://'): '//'}) }}`

but how to change `{{root.url}}`'s value? so i can use `{{root.url}}` to all of my template with https.

Thank you

Comment: which framework are you using?

Comment: i don't know exactly. its exlusive service. and i think provider self custom.

Comment: Which other attribute have the root element? Can you provide a dump of the root variable?